# MATLAB : cellfun and two variables function

Tags: matlab, vectorization, cell-array

temptemp is 1 X 44 cell : every cell is 1 X 3130 array double.

tempwmul is 1 X 44 cell : every cell is 1 X 1 trained network.

I want to simulate every network with the relative array double :

```
for ilog=1:44

tempoutemp{ilog} = sim(tempwmul{ilog},temptemp{ilog}); 

end
```

in vectorized mode using cellfun :

```
tempoutemp=cellfun(@sim,tempwmul,temptemp,'UniformOutput', false);
```

The code doesn't return errors but in vectorized mode it uses always the first network
for all array data and result is obviously different...some help?

Comment: Does calling it like `tempoutemp=cellfun(@sim,tempwmul.',temptemp,'UniformOutput', false);` help? For stuff like `bsxfun` at least you need to have non-equal singleton dimensions.

Comment: `cellfun` is not a *vectorised mode*.

Comment: I used tempoutemp=cellfun(@sim,tempwmul.',temptemp,'UniformOutput', false);     returns:

Error using cellfun
All of the input arguments must be of the same size and shape.
Previous inputs had size 44 in dimension 1. Input #3 has size 1. Are you sure all apostrophe and comma are correct?

Comment: It seems cellfun is a vectorized mode :  file:///D:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Emi/Documenti/MATLAB/TEMP/cellfun/New%20Functions%20for%20Vectorizing%20Operations%20on%20Any%20Data%20Type%20-%20MATLAB%20&%20Simulink.htm

Answer (score 0):

As Sardar Usama said: cellfun is not a vectorised mode, as far as I know.

Anyhow, if you truly fancy to use the functional style (for style's reasons, not for performance), I guess you could do:

```
tempoutemp = arrayfun (@(idx) sim(tempwmul{idx}, temptemp{idx}), 1 : length(temptemp), 'Uni', 0);
```

Comment: Other ways, using cellfun:

1) define a new data structure where each row defines your inputs. So element i would be {tempwmul{i}, temptemp{i} }
then it would be cellfun(@(x) sim(x{:}, newStruct, 'Uni', 0);

Comment: I tried : tempoutemp = arrayfun (@(idx) sim(tempwmul{idx}, temptemp{idx}), 1 : length(temptemp), 'Uni', 0); and it works but I have the same problem : it uses always the first network to sim all the data sets.

Comment: cellfun(@(x) sim(x{:}), newStruct, 'Uni', 0);  Can you explain me better what do you mean for newStruct? Is it a 44X2 cell where each cell is 1X1 cell? I tried many times but I failed!

Comment: Is length of temptemp 44? What do you get if you run size(temptemp)? And length(temptemp)?

Comment: It's writed in my main question :

temptemp is 1 X 44 cell : every cell is 1 X 3130 array double.

tempwmul is 1 X 44 cell : every cell is 1 X 1 trained network.

Thanks

Comment: The code I have posted is equivalent to your for loop. Please check your inputs. You would find the k-th result on the l-th component of tempoutemp. Unless you have some nasty side effects in assigning the variables, but you would find the same on your for loop, I guess.